# Returns tweets created before the given date

Tags: twitter

i have get count of the all tweets. but now i want to get all tweets till given date. i have get count of tweets using following line of the code.please any one given me the hint to get the tweets till given date that how i can pass the given date as parameter for getting count of the tweets.

```
$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $access_token['oauth_token'], $access_token['oauth_token_secret']);
$user = $connection->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?screen_name=" . $twitteruser);
$tweets = intval($user->statuses_count);
```

Comment: Here's a hint https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public

Comment: Try [HERE](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/user_timeline) - see the section about `max_id`.